# Exploring Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am learning java and identifying the best way to write unit tests. I have a simple xml parsing program, where I am looking for the best way to write test cases for the `SchemaValidator` class using `JUnit` and `Mockito`. Below is the class

```
public class SchemaValidator {

    private static final String SCHEMA_FILE = "/Schema.xsd";

    private File xml;

    public SchemaValidator(File xml) {
        this.xml = xml;
    }

    /**
     * Confirms if the schema is valid for the given xml file
     *
     * @return  {@code true} if schema is valid
     *          {@code false} otherwise
     */
    public boolean isValidSchema() {

        try {
            SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(SchemaValidator.class.getResourceAsStream(SCHEMA_FILE)));
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            validator.validate(new StreamSource(xml));
        } catch (IOException | SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

How could I test this class? Should I use dummy xml files (with valid and invalid schemas) locally to test the validator behavior or should be possible to achieve by mocking? What is the best practice? Would appreciate if explained with example test cases for the above.

Comment: One hint: with Mockito is it not possible to mock `static` methods. For this usage PowerMock can be used.

Answer (score 0):

As in your case you are not concerned with any database connectivity or any service layer, you should not use mock, use the dummy XML and test it.